# python get file process name on cmd using netstat command

Tags: python, winapi, subprocess, netstat

I want make a simple program to get the web server active on my local.
I have try to create some code, this code i working well in windows 7 64bit. but when I run my code on windows XP32 bit, this code make a windows XP hang.

can you help me to explain why this code make the windows XP hang ?

```
def get_web_server():
    import win32api
    import subprocess
    try:
        cmd = 'for /f "usebackq tokens=5" %i in (`"netstat -aon | findstr "0.0:80""`) do @wmic PROCESS get Name,ProcessId,ExecutablePath | findstr "%i"'
        output = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True).communicate()
        try:
            windows_exe = (output[0].split('\r\n')[0].strip().split()[0])
        except:
            windows_exe = None
        try:
            language, codepage = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(windows_exe, '\\VarFileInfo\\Translation')[0]
            stringFileInfo = u'\\StringFileInfo\\%04X%04X\\%s' % (language, codepage, "FileDescription")
            description = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(windows_exe, stringFileInfo)
        except:
            description = None

    except:
        description = None

    return description

print get_web_server()
```

sample output in win7 64bit when I'm using XAMPP

> Apache HTTP Server

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import subprocess
import re
import win32api
pid=subprocess.check_output('netstat.exe -abno | find /i "listening" |find ":80"', shell=True).split('\n', 1)[0].split()[-1]
webserver= subprocess.check_output('tasklist /FI "PID eq '+pid+'" /v /fo List', shell=True).splitlines()[-1].split("Window Title:", 1)[1].rsplit("Window Title:", 1)[0].strip()
def getFileDescription(windows_exe):
    try:
        language, codepage = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(windows_exe, '\\VarFileInfo\\Translation')[0]
        stringFileInfo = u'\\StringFileInfo\\%04X%04X\\%s' % (language, codepage, "FileDescription")
        description = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(windows_exe, stringFileInfo)
    except:
        description = "unknown"
    return description
print getFileDescription(webserver)
```

Output for above is "Apache HTTP Server"

I don't know why your's doesn't work in XP, but try the code above (Python 2.7)

Basically: executes command> gets relevant line> gets last word(PID) in output> passes pid to tasklist> goes to relevant line in tasklist> prints first word.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I mean the output not like, the output is the description of the file name. ex: file httpd.exe -> output `Apache HTTP Server`

Comment: Thanks bro, but I have found other alternative to find that. using `psutil` modul.